# Salesforce page popup opens with another url

Tags: javascript, popup, window, salesforce, parent

on the standard account layout i have a custom button that opens a new popup window with a visualforce page. My problem is that the layout page have an url like xxx.**salesforce.com**/xxxxxx and the popup page opens in url like x.xxx.visual.**force.com**/apex/myPageName
So i can not access parent window, for example reload it with window.opener.location.href I become an error: Permission denied to access property 'href'. 
Do you have an idea how i can open popup in same url?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was: i used a redirection to the visualforce page (not a popup window).

Answer (score 1):

Visualforce pages always open under the visual.force domain this is to stop Cross-Site Scripting attacks being embedded in visualforce pages accessing your data.

The simplest way to achieve what you're after is to server your account layout from the visual.force domain by creating a visualforce page something like the below

```
<apex:page standartcontroller="Account">
   <apex:detail />
</apex:page>
```